# oninput/onkeyup/onkeydow/onpropertychange doesn't work in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

As you might have noticed from the title I'm trying to make an event work properly and IE is giving me a hard time. I have tried all possible combinations, none of them seems to work.

I'm trying to mimic the Google suggestions list. A visitor should be able to come down in the list using the arrow keys, which is a Jquery keydown event. This event however also renders the request for the suggestion list at the same time in IE8 so the therefore the arrow keys function comes to an end (because of the request that is being maid.)

I know there must be a simple solution to this, but I can't see it.Help is appreciated. This is a demo: [at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ituwes/3/edit)

It works in all browsers but not in IE.

Comment: are you actually using for search? if not it might be worth looking at http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: How does this help me with my problem?

Comment: because if your not using it for search then chosen.js might be suitable for your needs, and means you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: This code is different in every angle...

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching the events before the elements exist.

Always work with elements only inside `$(document).ready()` method to be sure they exist and loaded in the document.

In your specific case, just move all the code:

```
el("inp").oninput=function(){
  addScript("http://www.google.nl/complete/search?callback=suggest&q="+this.value);
}

$('#inp').keydown(
function (e){
    var curr = $('#test').find('.current');
    //......
}
//.....
```

To be inside the `$(document).ready(` you already have.

Live test case that works for me in IE as well: http://jsfiddle.net/n7qAD/12/
(Your original code really didn't work in IE)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it still doesn't work for me...I'm using IE8 on windows 7.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work there either. I think because "oninput" doesn't work in IE, which is basically the problem. You can change the "oninput" in to "onpropertychange" than it will work. However you will not be able to come down in the list using the arrow keys. This is because (first) the input field is getting a new value which then (second) sets off a new event which is a request for the 'script'(suggestions). This is the problem in a nutshell. Its an annoying loop which I can't seem to break down.

Comment: Hmm.. sorry don't have any new idea how to solve this then. Is it working fine with IE9?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have IE9 installed, this is a computer at work. But I don't really care about IE9 since most people are using xp

Comment: If you can show me how to exclude the arrow keys when typing in the input field then this will solve the problem. I know how to include something with "if()" but I don't know how to exclude..

Comment: What do you mean by "exclude  the arrow keys"?

Comment: Well the problem occurs when you want to come down in the suggestions list using the arrow keys. When you for instance come down with the arrow key a new event is being triggered which will set the value of this list, this is the code that does that: `if(e.keyCode==40)
        {
            var search_terms = $('li.current').text();
            $('#inp').val(search_terms);
        }` Unfortunately this also triggers the event to send the request for whatever is in the input. It does that because the arrow key is **ALSO** a key, and the event is "onkeyup/down"

Comment: So excluding the arrow keys (from the event onkeyup/down) will solve the problem

Comment: Inside the function add `e.preventDefault();` and it should cancel any further events from triggering.

Comment: It doesn't work, guess my theory was not right. Thanks anyway